# Android Alarmmanager using Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I have an application for android using PhoneGap.
I want to create a system of four alarms. Each alarm set will be repeated in 24 of 24.
How do I create it? and how can I remove the alarm, whenever the user to set a new time for a touch of alarm?
I like to use PhoneGap, keep the clock with localStorage!

Comment: possible duplicate of [AlarmManager with phonegap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104144/alarmmanager-with-phonegap)

Answer (score 3):

PhoneGap has no support for `AlarmManager` AFAIK.

Comment: but to create a plugin you have access to alarmmanager.
I wanted to know was using the plugin how can I create 4 different alarms, set the time for each one of them and whenever any of the alarms has been amended to remove the earlier hours

Comment: @Filipe Cunha: When you want to remove an alarm, call `cancel()` on `AlarmManager` with the appropriate `PendingIntent`.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for can be achieved using the [LocalNotication plugin](https://github.com/olore/LocalNotifications). In my own app i use it to set up a daily reminder, theoretically it can set up several of those at specific times.

Setting up daily alarm from your html5 app then is as simple as follows:

```
    plugins.localNotification.add({
        date : new Date(),
        message : "Phonegap - Local Notification\r\nSubtitle comes after linebreak",
        ticker : "This is a sample ticker text",
        repeatDaily : true,
        id : 1
    });
```

You can create different alarms by using a unique id, which may also be cancelled and/or recreated (thus modified) individually before their alarm time, if needed.

Comment: But this will only work if the app is running, but if app is off and user are doing something else in his/her device then it will not show this notification. can you help me ?

Comment: @chintankhetiya - It will work _no matter_ if the app is running or not. That's the whole point here (the plugin wraps access to AlarmManager and alike). Even should restore the alarm after reboot.

Comment: @Philzen The LocalNotification Plugin does not work if the application has been quit also it will only show the notification in the notification drawer but will not show some kind of alert when the phone in locked which is required to build an alarm app.