# AlarmManager with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, alarmmanager

I'm using the StatusBarNotification plugin (Android) for Phonegap to fire a notification. Now I want to to this at a specific time, and from what I've read I have to use Android's AlarmManager. I've tried some approaches, but can't seem to get it to work.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

EDIT:
I can get the notification to show if I put the code in onReceive() to showNotification().
The problem seems to be that the receiver doesn't receive the Alarm-thingy. Probably because  I don't have the right action in the IntentFilter.

this is my code. I've build it from the StatusBarNotification plugin for Phonegap, found [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification)

```
public class StatusBarNotification extends Plugin {
//  Action to execute
public static final String ACTION="notify";

private Context context;
BroadcastReceiver receiver;

public StatusBarNotification() {
    this.receiver = null;
}

public void setContext(PhonegapActivity ctx) {
    super.setContext(ctx);
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(); //Dunno what to put here
    if(receiver == null) {
        this.receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("Notification", "inside onReceive");
                /*int icon = R.drawable.notification;
                long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
                NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, context.getClass());
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
                Notification noti = new Notification(icon, "NOTIFICATION", when);
                noti.setLatestEventInfo(context, "TITLE", "TEXT", contentIntent);
                manager.notify(1, noti);
                */
            }
        };
        ctx.registerReceiver(this.receiver, intentFilter);
    }
}

/**
 *  Executes the request and returns PluginResult
 *
 *  @param action       Action to execute
 *  @param data         JSONArray of arguments to the plugin
 *  @param callbackId   The callback id used when calling back into JavaScript
 *
 *  @return             A PluginRequest object with a status
 * */
@Override
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray data, String callbackId) {
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

    context = this.ctx.getApplicationContext();

    PluginResult result = null;
    if (ACTION.equals(action)) {
        try {

            String title = data.getString(0);
            String body = data.getString(1);
            Log.d("NotificationPlugin", "Notification: " + title + ", " + body);

            showNotification(title, body);
            result = new PluginResult(Status.OK);
        } catch (JSONException jsonEx) {
            Log.d("NotificationPlugin", "Got JSON Exception "
                    + jsonEx.getMessage());
            result = new PluginResult(Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
        }
    } else {
        result = new PluginResult(Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        Log.d("NotificationPlugin", "Invalid action : "+action+" passed");
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 *  Displays status bar notification
 *
 *  @param contentTitle Notification title
 *  @param contentText  Notification text
 * */
public void showNotification( CharSequence contentTitle, CharSequence contentText) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, ctx.getClass());
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 1234, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(ctx.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);

}

public void onDestroy() {
    if (this.receiver != null) {
        try {
            this.ctx.unregisterReceiver(this.receiver);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("LOG TAG", "Error unregistering network receiver: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should use LocalNotification.js to set alert for specific date and time. Because I had used it and it works fine.

Comment: Here is some documentation and an example from their github project page: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to write a PhoneGap plugin that can do the AlarmManager stuff.

Here are some examples of BroadcastReceivers in plugins:

https://github.com/callback/callback-android/blob/master/framework/src/com/phonegap/NetworkManager.java

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/PhoneListener/PhoneListener.java

Comment: That's one of the things I've tried. Probably didn't do it right tho. The one thing I have a "problem" with now, is what kind of action should I add to my IntentFilter? This is when I'm looking at the BroadcastReceiver examples.

Comment: I am actually about to tackle this myself for an app. I'll keep my eye on this Question and update if I find a solution...

Comment: Yeah, the internet moves fast. 4 years is a long time. Almost none of this informations is still useful, and where it is, the links will be clearly out of date. Apache Cordova is no longer called "callback" (thank goodness) and the old PhoneGap plugins repo has been superseded by something that itself has now been superseded. :)   TL;DR: Avoid 4 year old answers on SO?